# Permalink redirection from 'Day and name' to 'Post name'

Tags: permalinks, redirect

In my [blog](http://nishachor.com), I used the Day and name permalink structure for many days. Recently I came to know the SEO tips and made the permalink structure to Post name.

So I migrated from:

```
http://nishachor.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

to:

```
http://nishachor.com/%postname%/
```

It's very simple for me.

But not for the WordPress. ***I have many posts interlinked with each other, hand coded in posts.*** And their paths're in archive structure. Now in post name structure they are producing 404 error.

I used the [redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection), but doing a 301 redirection as mentioned above (from & to), is not working for me. I cleared my WP Super Cache's cached files and the browser's too.

In [Yoast's SEO Plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/) I got another permalink redirection, but not the one I want.

Please remember that, I don't have any structure like: domain.com?p=2 or something like that. I just want the archive portion in the URL (`%year%/%monthnum%/%day%`) should be removed and my posts to be loaded.

To me both the structure are very simple and should redirect from one to another, as they both are in a common platform. But why the permalink structure changing won't redirect itself? Now I need to edit each and every page to edit the hand-coded links. :(

The question is: **How can I solve the problem regarding permalink structure day and name to post name?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a redirect in your server/site configuration, for example a [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) in your .htaccess:

```sh
RedirectMatch permanent ^/\d\d\d\d/\d+/\d+/(.*) /$1
```

Comment: Thanks @toscho. I'm thinking to proceed for it. But for assurance of well being, I've edited some old links as %postname%. If the .htaccess edit redirects me from archive url to post url, then I want the assurance that it'll not affect if it found the %postname% url by default. Thanks in advance.