# 301 redirects in Headway based WordPress Site

Tags: redirect

I have a site built with Headway theme. Currently, URL of each of my blog posts is simply

```
http://example.com/blog-post-name
```

I'd like to add a folder so the URL would be:

```
http://example.com/blog/blog-post-name
```

If I add that folder, will the existing URLs automatically redirect to the new URLs which include that folder name, or would I have to manual create 301 redirects for each one?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Headway is not the issue, if Headway itself doesn't deal with any kind of 301 redirect.

And answer to the question is:
After having the folder in action if you change the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" in your `/wp-admin/options-general.php` (*Admin* » Settings » General) to the new address like:

```
http://example.com/blog/
```

Then the whole site will work with the new URL. (After the change you will just need to reenter the admin panel once - and that's all)

So, the first issue is solved.

But there could be an underlying issue with hard-coded inner links used in a blog. Suppose you linked one of your post with a simple text link (`<a href="http://example.com/blog-post-name-1">My blog post 1</a>`) — after the folder URL such links will generate 404, and that will be the problem. A similar issue is cited in one of my Question:

- [Permalink redirection from 'Day and name' to 'Post name' - WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98365/permalink-redirection-from-day-and-name-to-post-name)

So in that case you will need a `.htaccess` 301 redirection. But most of us are not so expert about `.htaccess`, so there are some plugins, can help us in our way.

Yoast have a good URL redirection plugin that can assist you in achieving this. And there are more on this category:

- [**Permalink Redirect Plugin** — Yoast.com](http://yoast.com/wordpress/permalink-redirect)
- [**Simple 301 Redirects** — WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects)
- [**Redirection** — WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)
- [**Blogger 301 Redirect** — WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/blogger-301-redirect/)
- [[...]](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/redirect)

With your input they will write `.htaccess` with right codes on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks Mayeenul!

Please read this post & leave your comments: 

http://headway101.com/headway-themes-review/

Comment: What is said in the "Search Engine Optimization" section is: *"...a 301 redirection field. Using this input, you can redirect..."* - it's saying you have built-in redirection ability with the theme. So, *WALA* - use it, and proceed. :)